# Would "return new Collection<T>(myList)" creates new collection object every time it's called?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a property:

```
public Collection<T> GameCollection
{
  get { return new Collection<T>(_myGameList); }
}
```

Would this method creates new Collection object every time it's called?

Comment: Certainly.  The odds that this is correct are very close to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would, because of the `new`. However it does not duplicate `myGameList` or its contents; it only makes new wrappers for the same `myGameList` (see [`Collection(IList<T>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx)).

If you want to prevent any of that and return a single collection, you can initialize a backing field instead and have your getter get that field (assuming `_myGameList` is already initialized too):

```
private Collection<T> _myGameCollection = new Collection<T>(_myGameList);

public Collection<T> GameCollection
{
  get { return _myGameCollection; }
}
```

Comment: I was doing that but I cannot imagine that for every list I want to expose, I have to create a wrapper.

Comment: Why not? Right now, for every list you want to expose, you're creating *many* wrappers -- a new one each time someone reads the property.

Comment: You're right. I thought it would somehow **magically** solved by the C# compiler, haha ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would create a new instance of `Collection<T>`, but each new instance would wrap the same underlying collection. (Per the docs, the constructor overload that takes `IList<T>` [wraps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx) the existing collection.)

So you'd return a new `Collection<T>` instance every time someone reads the property (which is wasteful and will cause a lot of garbage collection), but it would be returning something that logically acts like the same collection each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would. When you use the `new` keyword you always create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will create a new collection, but that's not as bad as it sounds.

For most types, the new collection only contains *references* to each item. In other words, it's only about an extra 4 bytes of RAM per object in the collection, rather than the cost of duplicating all the objects.  The exception, of course, is value types, but you need to be careful with using those anyway.